# doctrine queryBuilder returns error (twig?) and don't display datas for a One-To-Many relation, but my qquery returns me the good results

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, one-to-many, query-builder

I have these entites on my symfony project:

**Compteurs.php**

```
class Compteurs
{
    /**
     * @var \PointsComptage
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PointsComptage", inversedBy="compteurs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pointscomptage_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $pointsComptage;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ParametresMesure", mappedBy="compteurs")
     */
    private $parametresMesure;
```

**ParametresMesure.php:**

```
class ParametresMesure
{
    /**
     * @var Compteurs
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Compteurs", inversedBy="parametresMesure")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="compteurs_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $compteurs;
```

**PointsComptage.php**

```
class PointsComptage
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Compteurs", mappedBy="pointsComptage")
     */
    private $compteurs;
```

In my twig view, I am trying to recover all the `Compteurs.php` datas by passing by `PointsComptage.php`.

I have a *detail page*, with the **pointComptage.id** in *parameter*. In this detail page, I would like to display all `Compteurs.php` belong to the **PointComptage** **selected**, and all of the `ParametresMesure.php` linked to the **Compteurs** of the **selected** pointComptage.

This is my controller for this method:

```
public function detailsPointsComptageAction($id)
  {
    $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $arrayPC = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:PointsComptage')
                   ->findOneById($id); //pointComptage.id selected

      $arrayCompteur = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getRepository('MySpaceMyBundle:Compteurs')
                   ->getCompteursAttributesByPointsComptage($id); //method for recover datas linked to the compteurs belong to the  selectedpointComptage

      var_dump($arrayCompteur);

      return $this->render('MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:details.html.twig', array( 'arrayPC' => $arrayPC, 'arrayCompteur' => $arrayCompteur));
  }
```

Now, here's my PointsComptageRepository to create the dql queryBuilder I need to recover all datas:

```
public function getCompteursAttributesByPointsComptage($id)
  {
    $queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

    $queryBuilder
      ->select('pc')
      ->addSelect('c')
      ->from('MySpaceMyBundle:Compteurs', 'c')
      ->join('c.pointsComptage', 'pc')
      ->addSelect('pm')
      ->join('c.parametresMesure', 'pm')
      ->addSelect('tu')
      ->where('c.pointsComptage = pc.id')
      ->andWhere('pm.compteurs = c.id')
      ->andWhere('c.pointsComptage = :id')
      ->setParameter('id', $id);

      return $queryBuilder->getQuery()
                          ->getScalarResult();
  }
```

And this my twig view:

```
{% for compteur in arrayCompteur %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ compteur.matriculeCompteur}}</td> <!-- data 1 -->
    <td>{{ compteur.miseEnService|date("Y-m-d", "Europe/Paris")}}</td> <!-- data 2 -->
    <td>{{ compteur.miseHorsService|date("Y-m-d", "Europe/Paris")}}</td> <!-- data 3 -->
    <td class="no-cell-padding">
      <table class="inner-table table stripe row-border order-column display table-bordered table-hover compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        {# {% for compteur in arrayCompteurs.parametresMesure %} #}
          <tr>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
            <td>test</td>
          </tr>
        {# {% endfor %} #}
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, I make a var dump of my `$arrayCompteur`, which returns me this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=16)
      'c_id' => int 5
      'c_matriculeCompteur' => string 'egfizegilf88' (length=12)
      'c_miseEnService' => 
        object(DateTime)[2255]
          public 'date' => string '2012-05-15 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'c_miseHorsService' => 
        object(DateTime)[2254]
          public 'date' => string '2015-06-19 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'pc_id' => int 1
      'pc_invariantPointComptage' => string 'invariant 1' (length=11)
      'pc_nomPointComptage' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
      'pc_codeDistribution' => string 'code test 1' (length=11)
      'pc_localisationPointComptage' => string 'local test 1' (length=12)
      'pm_id' => int 1
      'pm_codeParametre' => string '658' (length=3)
      'pm_nomParametre' => string 'test 658' (length=8)
      'tu_id' => int 1
      'tu_nomTypeUnite' => string 'kW' (length=2)
      'tp_id' => int 1
      'tp_nomTypeParametre' => string 'puissance' (length=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=16)
      'c_id' => int 5
      'c_matriculeCompteur' => string 'egfizegilf88' (length=12)
      'c_miseEnService' => 
        object(DateTime)[2249]
          public 'date' => string '2012-05-15 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'c_miseHorsService' => 
        object(DateTime)[2360]
          public 'date' => string '2015-06-19 00:00:00' (length=19)
          public 'timezone_type' => int 3
          public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
      'pc_id' => int 1
      'pc_invariantPointComptage' => string 'invariant 1' (length=11)
      'pc_nomPointComptage' => string 'test 1' (length=6)
      'pc_codeDistribution' => string 'code test 1' (length=11)
      'pc_localisationPointComptage' => string 'local test 1' (length=12)
      'pm_id' => int 3
      'pm_codeParametre' => string 'gjgfjgfj489489' (length=14)
      'pm_nomParametre' => string 'hyhfhfhfhf' (length=10)
      'tu_id' => int 2
      'tu_nomTypeUnite' => string 'kWh' (length=3)
      'tp_id' => int 2
      'tp_nomTypeParametre' => string 'Ã©nergie' (length=8)
```

So, like I see, I recover my datas I need, but I have this error:

> Key "matriculeCompteur" for array with keys "c_id,
>   c_matriculeCompteur, c_miseEnService, c_miseHorsService, pc_id,
>   pc_invariantPointComptage, pc_nomPointComptage, pc_codeDistribution,
>   pc_localisationPointComptage, pm_id, pm_codeParametre,
>   pm_nomParametre, tu_id, tu_nomTypeUnite, tp_id, tp_nomTypeParametre"
>   does not exist in MySpaceMyBundle:MyFolder:details.html.twig at line
>   41

the line 41 corresponds to `<td>{{ compteur.matriculeCompteur}}</td>`.

How can I display correctly my datas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I found my solution. The problem was in my twig view and not in my query.

For recover all data, I need to loop on all of my association. Look at my twig code for the table body:

```
<tbody>
  {% for compteur in arrayCompteur %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ compteur.matriculeCompteur}}</td>
      <td>{{ compteur.miseEnService|date("Y-m-d", "Europe/Paris")}}</td>
      <td>{{ compteur.miseHorsService|date("Y-m-d", "Europe/Paris")}}</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
              <th>Code</th>
              <th>Nom</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Unité</th>
            </tr>
          {% for parametre in compteur.parametresMesure %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ parametre.codeParametre}}</td>
              <td>{{ parametre.nomParametre}}</td>
              <td>{{ parametre.typesUnite}}</td>
              <td>{{ parametre.typesParametre}}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Now all my datas are displayed correctly in my table.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have field called "matriculeCompteur" in the array, the field is called "c_matriculeCompteur".

Instead of

```
<td>{{ compteur.matriculeCompteur}}</td>
```

You should use

```
<td>{{ compteur.c_matriculeCompteur}}</td>
```

or

```
<td>{{ attribute(compteur, 'c_matriculeCompteur') }}</td>
```

Comment: look at my answer, my problem comes from twig and not from my queryBuilder. The message error is normal (for name's fields), because the request returns me the fields of my database, not of my entity object. In my entity I have a field name **matriculeCompteur**, and in my database, this field is named **matricule_compteur**. Thank you for your answer.